# Best development board for cmos camera project

Tags: board

I want to interface a high definition (best quality) cmos camera with a development board. I have use arduino, raspberry pi and pic microcontrollers for some projects in the past but i dont know a suitable development board for this project. Anyone that has an idea?

EDIT: I want first to interface one cmos camera. Then move to 2-3 and try make image triangulation with the images.

Answer (score 2):

It might be helpful to let us know your application, as this will influence the design quite a bit.

I'm actually working on a fairly similar project (creating a digital rangefinder camera). If you are not picky about the particular sensor, you should check out the raspberry pi camera module: http://downloads.element14.com/raspberry-pi-camera/.

In general, camera modules are fairly easy to interface with a powerful enough microcontroller, especially if the camera module can perform a large amount of onboard processing and you have good documentation (which is always a challenge). The Omnivision modules (which are available on various hobbyist locations such as eBay) can do onboard JPEG compression, which is essential if your micro has very little RAM.

Depending on your application, a USB camera might be fine as well (for example, if you are doing image processing with OpenCV). Either the raspberry pi or the pandaboard/beagleboard will do well here, since raw processing power (and having a good USB host module) is the most important thing. So it really depends on your application.

Finally, if you have a specific sensor that you want to use such as in my case, usually the only choice is to develop a custom driver using a FPGA. This is because fast readout and control of the electronic shutter of an image sensor, whether CCD or CMOS requires generating multiple precise timings. At least with a CMOS sensor, you do not have to worry about the odd voltages that the various biasing circuits require, but typically you need a state machine which can drive a dozen outputs or so at several MHz. This is the path that I have to take with my project, since I am using a specialized full frame (24x36mm) sensor.

Answer (score 2):

Any board will do to be honest. You need a board with a strong microprocessor, like the PI, and if you're not all that into creating your own modules, you can just buy a camera module from element14...

If you want crazy HD 1080p quality, you're not really going to be able to process it very efficiently on a weak board, such as the raspberry PI or arduino. Try implemeting your own board with Microchip PIC or DSP chips.